# CSV join some rows that have the same id

Tags: ruby, bash, csv, awk

I have a `CSV` file like this

```
1,A,abc
2,A,def
1,B,smthing
1,A,ghk
5,C,smthing
```

Now I want to join all the rows that have the same value at row 2. In this case is row with the second element is A. The return file should be

```
1,A,abcdef,ghk
3,B,smthing
5,C,smthing
```

I'm trying with `awk` and I can get the second and the third fields but not whole file like this

```
awk -F, '{a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]$3:$3;}END{for (i in a)print i","a[i];}' old_file.csv > new_file.csv
```

### Update

I solved my problem with 2 command. First create a new_file.csv (command above)
Second command will join old_file with new_file

```
awk -F, 'NR == FNR {a[$1] = $2;} NR != FNR && a[$2] {print $1","$2","a[$2];}' new_file.csv old_file.csv > last_file.csv
```

The last_file.csv looks like this

```
1,A,abcdefghk
2,A,abcdefghk
1,B,smthing
1,A,abcdefghk
5,C,smthing
```

So, how should I make a better command from those 2 commands?
Thank you!

Comment: You’re output doesn’t match with input. How does row with B get number 3? What about row with A that has number 2? Is there a `,` missing after `abc` and `def` for output row 1?

Comment: SO sorry. I made a little mistake when converting from my real data. I corrected my command. Thank you @jaypalsingh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One awk is enough:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=a[$2]==""?$3:a[$2] $3;next}{$3=a[$2]}1' FS=, OFS=, file file

1,A,abcdefghk
2,A,abcdefghk
1,B,smthing
1,A,abcdefghk
5,C,smthing
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==FNR{a[$2]=a[$2]==""?$3:a[$2] $3;next}` merge records to array a (key is column 2)
- `$3=a[$2]` read the input file again, change column 3 with new value.

#### Add the command to remove the duplicate records (column 2), keep the first one.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=a[$2]==""?$3:a[$2] $3;next}!b[$2]++{$3=a[$2];print}' FS=, OFS=, file file

1,A,abcdefghk
1,B,smthing
5,C,smthing
```

Comment: Work great. Thank BMW.

Comment: one last thing. What should I want to remove the first 1,A and 2,A. I want to make something like:
    1,B,smthing
    1,A,abcdefghk
    5,C,smthing

Comment: do you mean to remove duplicate records and keep the last?

Comment: yes. I want to get the first or last duplicate record.

Comment: I did the update, get the first duplicate record only, is it fine?